# Calling functions from XML in C++

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, events, signals

I am intending to add in XML parsing to a project i'm working on. This will need to allow the software not only to load and save settings but also call functions when required.

I can see that loading and saving settings is not an issue, however, the asynchronous events that will need to be triggered could potentially be a bit tricky.

The application will be driven remotely, and events will need to be triggered, e.g. starting playback. This should be done using the XML.

One way I can see of doing this is shown below. For each element the XML will contain Settings and Signals. For loading and saving, the signals are not required, just the settings. If however, a signal needs to be called, then its value will be set to 1 and the clock will be toggled.

```
<SomeElement>
  <Settings>
    <setting1 value="1"/>
    <setting2 value="2"/>
  </Settings>
  <Signals>
    <clock value="0"/>
    <Signal1 value="1"/>
  </Signals>
</SomeElement>
```

Does this seem like a reasonable way of achieving this or is there a simpler / better way i'm unaware of.

I currently plan to use pugixml as the XML parser, however, it is likely I will write a wrapper around it.

Thanks for your help

Comment: What's a "signal"? What does "calling a signal" mean? You haven't provided enough information for us to give a meaningful answer.

Comment: just use a scripting language ... this "solution" can easily become a real mess

Comment: This is not even a proper XML syntax:
  `<Settings>
    setting1=1
    setting2=2
  </Settings>`
It should rather be:
  `<Settings>
    <setting1 value="1"/>
    <setting2 value="2"/>
  </Settings>`
and so on...

Comment: Have edited the question to give a slightly more accurate description of the issue.

Comment: According to your edit you need something like semaphores or something safer like sockets, i honestly can't imagine how you end up using XML for this, it's totally on another planet.

Comment: I would look at something which brings reflection support to C++, such as Qt (and with that I'd probably use Qt's XML classes for parsing, too). That way you can call methods by the name you read from XML, instead of needing to keep track of XML string -> C++ method mappings yourself. But since the whole things seems a bit sketchy, I'd at least do a prototype version first to get better understanding of the problem domain, to be thrown out before starting final implementation.

Comment: Of course this can be done, but sending commands via XML file is not usual and reasonable way to do it. You will end up periodically (may be often) reading XML data from external source just to get some changes. And if file is big enough it is absolutely insane to resend if often (over network?) and parse the data. Is that is what you want?

Comment: Some more research suggests that using something like SOAP http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_(protocol) could be the way forward.

Comment: @robby987 - Again, its main purpose to exchange data or to set initial conditions but not for sending commands. "Because of the verbose XML format, SOAP can be considerably slower than competing middleware technologies such as CORBA or ICE. This may not be an issue when only small messages are sent." (Wikipedia)

Comment: "SOAP is the successor of XML-RPC" - RPC being remote procedure call.

Comment: I doubt speed is really that much of an issue, as the XML is unlikely to be that large.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: The "XML" you've provided above is not really valid XML unless your settings and signals are treated as plain text. Otherwise you'd have to use something like:

```
<Settings>
    <setting name="setting1" value="1" />
    <setting name="setting2" vakue="2" />
</Settings>
```

Also, if you require the elements of an XML file to be read in a certain order, you're not talking about XML, but plain text that looks like XML - the XML standard does require the elements to be delivered in the same order they are found within the file (only the level-structure is kept). So it might well be you read "setting2" before "setting1" and "signal" before "clock". To maintain a certain order, you'll need to use some "sort" attribute you can sort by.

What I'd do is to build some sort of "action list" - a list of things to do (set a setting or start an action) and fill this list parsing the XML file. Then, I'd iterate over the list and do what the action tells me to do.

This, however, can in no way be titled "calling functions from XML in C++" (which is not possible, as XML is nothing that can "run" in the way a program runs).

Comment: Ok, I've changed the XML according to the first comment.

Comment: If from an external unit, over the network, the xml is sent to the unit a number of times, the software should be able to determine that the signal has been set and that the clock has been changed. Alternatively, the clock could be not necessarily and simply triggering a change of the signal value (or Incrementing a count) for each call of the function.